# Submitting Spark application on YARN from Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, apache-spark

I am facing an issue when I try to submit my Spark application on Yarn from eclipse. I try to submit a simple SVM program, but i gives below error. I Have macbook, and I will be so thankful if somebody give me detailed answer

```
16/09/17 10:04:19 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Library directory '.../MyProject/assembly/target/scala-2.11/jars' does not exist; make sure Spark is built.
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.CommandBuilderUtils.checkState(CommandBuilderUtils.java:248)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.CommandBuilderUtils.findJarsDir(CommandBuilderUtils.java:368)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.YarnCommandBuilderUtils$.findJarsDir(YarnCommandBuilderUtils.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:500)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:834)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:500)
    at SVM.main(SVM.java:21)
```

Comment: Go to Run Configurations --> Environment in Eclipse and add the environment variable **SPARK_HOME** there.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh for your perfect answer. it worked :) but now i see this error

Comment: 16/09/17 14:44:56 WARN DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/marjanasgari/.sparkStaging/application_1474085529591_0014/__spark_libs__3176835706727949960.zip could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.

Comment: One of your datanode should be alive. I posted the comment as answer. Please accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to

> Run Configurations --> Environment

in Eclipse and add the environment variable **SPARK_HOME**.